# Handling Rejection Errors in Javascript Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js App and is using a function that returns a Promise, but it seems in some conditions it gives:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

And my server crashes.

Here is a simplifed code that does the crash if wifi is turned off:

```
checkip.getExternalIp().then(function (ip) {
  console.log("External IP = "+ip);
});
```

Is there a way to handle something like this?

Comment: `.catch` -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: ^ you should post this as an answer

Comment: Shortest correct answer on S O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two options. You can slap a `.catch` call on to the end of the promise, or you can provide a second callback to `.then` which runs in the failed case:

```
checkip.getExternalIp().then(function (ip) {
  console.log("External IP = "+ip);
}).catch(function(err) {
  // handle error here
});
```

or

```
checkip.getExternalIp().then(function (ip) {
  console.log("External IP = "+ip);
}, function(err) {
  // handle error here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ES2015 promises follow [the A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/). Thus, any promise has the possibility of generating an error that can be caught. So, to trap the error you are receiving simply supply a `catch` handler:

```
checkip.getExternalIp()
  .then(then_handler)
  .catch(catch_handler);
```

More complete examples are in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).